# WP 8.1 Silverlight: CoreWindow doesn't fire PointerXXX events

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I implementing some Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application, where I need to respond to Pointer events (related to gestures).

I planned to use CoreWindow, but for some reason PointerXXX events are not being fired. Do I miss something?

Here what I tried to do:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var w = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();

        w.PointerPressed += MainPage_PointerPressed;
    }

void MainPage_PointerPressed(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        //never fired
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is a DirectManipulation control (such as ScrollView) you won't be able to work with pointer events such as PointerMoved even with CoreWindow class. It is common issue on WP platform.